# How to link to a specific section in Rust documentation

Tags: rust, markdown, rust-cargo, rustdoc

Suppose I place a header in the documentation for a Rust module, `src/module_a/mod.rs`:

```markdown
# Header

Some text.
```

I know how to link to this header from other parts of `src/module_a/mod.rs` using standard markdown syntax, and I know how to link to `module_a` from other modules using standard Cargo doc syntax.  But I'm not sure how to link directly to Header within `module_a` from another module.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the `[text](path)` syntax and include a #-suffixed "anchor" for the heading. The path portion can still use Rust's shorthand syntax.

Here's an example that could be put in `module_b`:

```
//! Here's is a link to the [Header](crate::module_a#header) section.
```